# Can i open chrome without the maximise, close buttons, while it not being fullscreen

Tags: google-chrome

We are building a Point of Sale application (retail store, people walk in, list items, take payment).

We are currently using --app="" to launch the browser but we've found some retail staff are hitting X and closing the window without completing the order (and potentially handing over our products).

We don't want the window in fullscreen mode (otherwise we'd use --kiosk), but instead want something in the middle,

a kiosk style mode that isn't fullscreen.

I've read through the chrome flags, and can't seem to find anything that would suit.

Any thoughts on how we'd achieve that?

Comment: You might want to use the Chromium Embedded Framework instead -  https://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php?sid=777c87a50f89432bc1923df7afdc7025 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_Embedded_Framework  since you can control exactly what UI elements are included and how they react to the user,